# mlr3, don't understand the splitting part

Tags: r, validation, testing, training-data, mlr3

Hi everybody I'm new in the mlr3 universe and I'm currently trying to learn how to use it thanks to their book (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/Flexible-and-Robust-Machine-Learning-Using-mlr3-in-R.pdf).
I'm trying also to apply their methodology to my set of datas but I still don't understand something...They split the native dataset in two : train and test. Ok, but, what about the validation set for the hyperparametres tuning ??

Here is an example of my datas :

```
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P6", "P6", "P6"), 
    LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L),.Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), F1 = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
    0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 1.25, 0.625, 0.625, 
    1.25, 1.25, 1.25), F2 = c(1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0, 5, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1), F3 = c(0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 0, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0), F3 = c(0, 9, 0, 7, 4, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, there is a big imbalanced datas in this dataset (target = LesionResponse), I splitted like this :

An example of the code I use to create my train and test sets (too much long I admit...) :

```
data <- subset(data, select = -Loc_clean)
data$PatientID <- as.factor(data$PatientID)
task <- TaskClassif$new("data_DENY", data,"LesionResponse")

proportion_within_bounds <- FALSE

while (!proportion_within_bounds) {
  # Split data into train and test sets by PatientID
  set.seed(123) # Set a seed for reproducibility
  
  unique_patients <- unique(task$data()$PatientID)
  train_patients <- sample(unique_patients, size = round(0.7 * length(unique_patients)))
  train_set <- which(task$data()$PatientID %in% train_patients)
  test_set <- which(!task$data()$PatientID %in% train_patients)
  
  train_set_df <- task$data(rows = train_set)
  test_set_df <- task$data(rows = test_set)
  
  # Calculate the proportions of "1" in the train and test sets
  train_prop_1 <- sum(train_set_df$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(train_set_df)
  test_prop_1 <- sum(test_set_df$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(test_set_df)
  
  # Check if the proportions are within the specified bounds
  if (train_prop_1 >= 0.70 && train_prop_1 <= 0.75 &&
      test_prop_1 >= 0.70 && test_prop_1 <= 0.75) {
    proportion_within_bounds <- TRUE
  }
}

# Print the final train and test sets
print(train_set_df)
print(test_set_df)

# Print the final proportions
cat("Final proportion of '1' in the train set:", train_prop_1, "\n")
cat("Final proportion of '1' in the test set:", test_prop_1, "\n")
```

But, now, if I train my learners on the train set, how could I tune the hyper parameters ?? there is no validation set and I can't use the test set (only to "test" by essence...).

Another question, if I keep my column 'PatientID' to split the datas and keep all the uniqueID in the same groups, how could I keep it apart to train and predict with all the other features (there is no way and ID can participate in the composition of the model...) ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are many different ways of resampling in mlr3. Can you show us some code that doesn't work or doesn't do what you want?